# How to filter search form drop down menu in Rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, search, filter

I'm trying to filter selected options from 3 dropdown menus.
Here are my models:

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :skills
  has_and_belongs_to_many :jobs
  has_and_belongs_to_many :industries
end
```

and

```
class Industry < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :profiles
end
```

and

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :profiles
end
```

and

```
class Skill < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :profiles
end
```

**Views**

```
profiles/index.html.erb
```

I list all 3 drop down menus

```
<section class="top-search">
      <div class="container">
      <%= form_tag @filter, :method => :get do %>
        <%= select_tag "skills_id", options_from_collection_for_select(Skill.all, "id", "name"), prompt: "Specialized Skills" %>
        <%= select_tag "industries_id", options_from_collection_for_select(Industry.all, "id", "name"), prompt: "Industries" %>
        <%= select_tag "jobs_id", options_from_collection_for_select(Job.all, "id", "name"), prompt: "Job Functions" %>
        <%= submit_tag "Filter", name: nil, class:"btn btn-primary" %>
      <% end %>
      </div>
    </section>
```

And in the same page below the above section, I have another section where I want to display the filter result..

```
<section class="search-result">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row flex-container">
          <% @profiles.each do |profile| %>
            <div class="col-md-5 mentor-profile">
              <div class="media">
                <div class="media-left">
                  <%= link_to profile do %>
                    <%= image_tag profile.avatar.url(:thumb) %>
                  <% end %>
                </div>
                <div class="media-body">
                  <h4 class="media-heading">
                    <%=link_to profile do %>
                      <%= "#{profile.first_name }" " #{ profile.last_name}" %>
                    <% end %>
                  </h4>
                  <strong>Works at <%= profile.company %></strong>
                  <p><%= profile.city %>, <%= profile.country %></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="dvider"></div>
              <div class="profile-section">
                <h5>SUMMARY</h5>
                <p><%= profile.summary %></p>
              </div>
              <div class="profile-section">
                <h5>SPECIALIZED SKILLS</h5>
                <p><%= profile.skills.map(&:name).join(', ') %></p>
              </div>
              <div class="profile-section">
                <h5>CRITERIA MET</h5>
                <p>NEED TO WORK ON IT....</p>
              </div>

            </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

In Profiles Controller I defined a filter method:

```
  def filter
    @profiles = Profile.all
    @profiles = Profile.joins(:skills).where('skills.name = ?', params[:skill])
    @profiles = Profile.joins(:industries).where('industries.name = ?', params[:industry])
    @profiles = Profile.joins(:jobs).where('job.name = ?', params[:job])
  end
```

It seems filters works, the urls shows this `http://localhost:3000/profiles?utf8=%E2%9C%93&skills_id=13&industries_id=9&jobs_id=8`

But nothing got filtered.

How would I get it to work? I have seen similar cases where filter uses JS to filter the page and append the result (in my case `<section class="search-result">` section to the page).

Am I correct?

Comment: You are overriding your `@profiles` relation. Try `@profiles = @profiles.joins(...` instead.

Comment: Check out the ransack gem, (https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack) it looks like it could help in your situation.

Comment: @DanielRikowski First suggestion didn't work. I'm going through the gem doc, but not getting anywhere. I'd appreciate if you show heads up on how to do it. I never done it before. Thanks...